# Getting cron to include date in error log

Tags: linux, scripting, cron, logs

I have the following cron job running:

```
/home/ubuntu/scripts/austria/archive.sh >> /home/ubuntu/logs/austria/archive.log 2>> /home/ubuntu/logs/austria/archive.err
```

Every time the script runs, it makes a regular log file, and if there are errors, it updates the .err file with the errors. However, I was wondering if it would be possible to have the errors also include the date of the errors **in** the log. I'm very new to crontab, and I'm having trouble getting this to happen. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output to `ts(1)` of `moreutils` among other such similar utilities, which prefix any input with a time stamp:

```
% (echo hi; sleep 3; echo there) | ts
Aug 28 18:52:42 hi
Aug 28 18:52:45 there
%
```

So assuming you want timestamps on just standard error:

```
...archive.sh 2>&1 >>.../out.log | ts >>.../err.log
```

Note that this is really tricky, and important that the shell redirections happen exactly as written. This is what I used to verify the shell redirections:

```
$ perl -le 'print "out"; warn "err!\n"' 2>&1 >> out | sed 's/^/blah /' > err
$ cat out
out
$ cat err
blah err!
```

Another option would be to pipe the output to `logger`, in which case syslog would prefix the logs with a timestamp and then dump the logs into some logfile, depending on the syslog daemon settings.

Yet another option might be to directly edit `archive.sh` to include appropriate `date` call output for everything sent to stderr:

```
echo `date` oh no >&2
```